# Nested package stacks?

Tags: ros, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nested stacks, is it possible?

By nested stack I mean the setup similar to this:

```
ros_workspace (set up by rosws)
  | some_stack
     | another_stack
     | ...
  | package1
  | ...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49582/nested-stacks?/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-12-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-12-02**:
I think you should be way more precise why you want what is not possible or at least sensible according to the ROS environment definition. Oh, I heard in near catkin-future stacks are obsolete anyway.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-02**:
@liborw please read the [support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support) before posting. Please tag your question appropriately and be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nested stacks won't be possible, but if you want to sort a lot of stacks into a few groups, just put those stacks into simple directories like so:

```
ros_workspace (or any directory put into ROS_PACKAGE_PATH)
  | navigation
     | stack1 (with stack.xml)
        | package1 (with manifest.xml)
        | package2 (with manifest.xml)
     | stack2 (with stack.xml)
        | package3 (with manifest.xml)
        | package4 (with manifest.xml)
  | objectdetection
     | stack3 (with stack.xml)
        | package5 (with manifest.xml)
        | package6 (with manifest.xml)
     | stack4 (with stack.xml)
        | package7 (with manifest.xml)
        | package8 (with manifest.xml)
```

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-03**:
Nested stacks are not supported. But with Groovy, stacks are being supplanted by metapackages, which *can* depend on other metapackages.